# How to remove item from Firebase chat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firebase

I have followed the Firebase tutorial on their website to create a chat window. However I'm not sure how to remove a message from the chat. I can add messages but not remove them.

Here is the code for the chat:

```
     var myDataRef = new Firebase('https://q05v01tsqpu.firebaseio-demo.com/');
      $('#message').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
          var name = $('#name').val();
          var text = $('#message').val();
          myDataRef.push({name: name, text: text});
          $('#message').val('');
        }
      });
      myDataRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
        var message = snapshot.val();
        displayChatMessage(message.name, message.text);
      });
      function displayChatMessage(name, text) {
        $('<div/>').text(text).prepend($('<b/>').text(name+': ')).appendTo($('#messagesDiv'));
        $('#messagesDiv')[0].scrollTop = $('#messagesDiv')[0].scrollHeight;
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

This will delete everything

```
myDataRef.remove()
```

This will remove any childs under it

```
myDataRef.child(key).remove()
```